# Dynamic Content JSP Loader

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp page in which i have a drop down menu. Based on the value the user selects from the menu, I need to load different contents on the page. How do i achieve this? I am new to JSP and hence not aware.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496). What may be confusing you is that [Stack Overflow is not like all those other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/172496)

Comment: what is the code that you have tried

Comment: There are several ways for to do it

Comment: @PaulVargas Can u gv one example? tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

This a example loads a new page:

```
<select name="exampleselect" onchange="window.location=this.value;">
  <option value="Please select...">Please select...</option>
  <option value="page1.html">Example1</option>
  <option value="page2.html">Example2</option>
  <option value="page3.html">Example3</option>
</select>
```

Use `onChange` event for change something in the page.